# Is it possible to deploy a Qt app to Mac OS without a Mac?

Tags: qt

The question may seem naive, but I couldn't find a clear answer anywhere after searching on Google.

I'm developing a Qt application for a client that uses Windows and Mac OS machines. I'm using elementary OS myself, though I have a Windows machine available for deploying to Windows. Though, I don't have a Mac available.

My question is: can I deploy a Qt application for Mac OS without a Mac, or do I have to get one somehow to compile and deploy from it?

I quickly looked into continuous integration (more precisely Travis-CI since they provide a Mac OS environment) but I found that there wasn't official support for Qt and that many people couldn't get it to work.

Comment: I've had success in the past with running macos in a vm, it was able to compile Qt project binaries. IIRC it is illegal to run macos on a non mac system tho, something to keep in mind. If you are willing to pay a bit, you can rent an on-demand macos cloud instance.

Comment: It is possible to create Qt application with travis for macOs. I've been doing so successfully for quite a while. I have linked you my CI-scripts, but be aware that they do much other stuff, tailored to my needs. But you can use them as inspiration: https://github.com/Skycoder42/QtModules/tree/master/ci/osx

Comment: @Felix thanks for this, I'll try and hopefully get it to work in my case